# ($L$ is an affine space of dimension one) $\Leftrightarrow$ ($L$ is a line)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Definition (I):
Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n $ with $x\neq y$.
A line in $\mathbb{R}^n$  is defined as the subset $L=\{t(y-x)+x | t\in \mathbb{R}\}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Statement: ($L$ is an affine space of dimension one) $\Leftrightarrow$ ($L$ is a line)

Proof:

i) $\Rightarrow $

Let $L\subset \mathbb{R}^n $ be an affine space with $\dim L =1$. So a linear subspace $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n $ with $\dim U = 1$ exists and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n $ exists such that $L=U+x$.
I could argue that $U$ is a linear subspace with dimension one, consequentially $U$ is a closed set and every element $u\in U$ can be represented as $u=t\cdot y$ with $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and a fixed $y\in U\setminus \{0\}$.
So $L$ can be represented as a line $L=\{x+t\cdot y | t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ but in the definition (I) the form is $L=\{t(y-x)+x | t\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Is that a problem?

ii) $\Leftarrow $

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n $ with $x\neq y$ than $L=\{t(y-x)+x | t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ defines a line.
Define $U=\{t(y-x)| t\in \mathbb{R}\}$. $U$ is a lineare subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n $ with dimension one. Every $a\in L$ has the form $a=x+t(y-x)$ with $t(y-x)\in U$ therefore $L$ can be written as $L=x+U$ and is an affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n $
How can I argue that $\dim L = 1$?
There is no basis I could define for $L$ - I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad (i): Just define $y' := y+x$, then your line will be of the form $\{x+t\cdot (y' - x)\}$.

Ad (ii): $U=\{t\cdot (y-x)\,|\, t\in\mathbb R\}$, which is the linear span of the set $\{y-x\}$ (consisting only of a single vector), so $y-x$ would be a basis vector. The dimension of $L$ is specified via the dimension of $U$.

All of the above only holds for $x\neq y$.